# JQuery. Disable minDate in DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I create DateTimePicker like this:

```
 $wnd.$("#" + id).datetimepicker({
    minDate: 0,
       .............
 });
```

I want to disable minDate option prorammatically. I try next, but it don't work:

```
      try {
        $wnd.$("#" + id).datetimepicker({minDate: new Date(1970, 01 - 1, 01)}); 
      }
      catch(e) {
        $wnd.$("#" + id).datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(1970, 01 - 1, 01));        
      }
```

P.S.Do not pay attention to the `$wnd` variable. It's work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming u're talking about [this plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), wich is based on [the jquery-ui-datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), just set `minDate` to `null` according to [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate):

> Set a minimum selectable date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '-1y -1m'), or **null for no limit**.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $wnd.$("#" + id).datetimepicker(
    'option', 
    'minDate', new Date()
   ));
```